# Own PEM file in initramfs

Tags: initramfs, wget

I am currently tinkering with the subiquity installer.
I would like to load the iso from a local https address
However the intitramfs keeps saying:

`wget: error getting response: connection reset by peer`

This must be a certificate issue as I get certificate errors when I run the same command on my local machine.
But wget in initramfs is different from the GNU wget.
Is there any way to import my own certificate into the initramfs and make initramfs wget use this certificate? Or is there a kernel option to tell initramfs to disable ssl checks?

Answer (score 0):

so well we ended up building a static GNU wget, replacing it in the initrd and now it works.